# SQL ORDER BY a string value: What is it comparing? (Case sensitive?)

Tags: mysql, sql, sorting, sql-order-by

I would like to know what exactly SQL is comparing when we use the ORDER BY statement. More specifically, I'm interested in the comparison when it compares string. Supposedly it is sorting it alphabetically, but what is it actually comparing?

My hunch tells me it could be comparing ASCII values of the characters starting from the left, which would also imply that the sorting is case sensitive ('Btest' would be smaller than 'atest'), but I am unable to find a source confirming this.

Comment: For character data, it mostly depends on the character collation settings for your database/table.

Comment: From my understanding is converting ASCII to HEX  , to understand this better , compare 90 to 100 (as strings in sql), 100  will come back as smaller, the reason for this 9 returns a bigger number than 1 when converted to hex. so this is something to look out for when comparing strings

Comment: which SQL are you using? you may check the corresponding documentation directly

Comment: 'On character type columns, sorting—like all other comparison operations—is normally performed in a case-insensitive fashion. This means that the order is undefined for columns that are identical except for their case. You can force a case-sensitive sort for a column by using BINARY like so: ORDER BY BINARY col_name.' -https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sorting-rows.html

Comment: I think visual it be better to understand what I mentioned earlier , https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/qS112jkz8GwJdNKwWyYZgC/0 . right here we are selecting same data just changing data type. and we have different results.

Comment: You are not the only one unable to find any worthwhile mysql documentation , even the mysql internals manual shies away from specifying the sort algorithm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MySQL, it depends on the effective collation. Collation is the set of rules that determine the position of characters in an ordered set and what characters are considered equal, and typically involve natural language rules. For example, Spanish used to have `ch` as an independent letter located betwen `c`  and `d` and then switched to being just individual `c` and `h`; MySQL has collations for both.

You can see available collations with [these commands](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/show-collation.html):

```
SHOW COLLATION; -- Display all
SHOW COLLATION WHERE charset = 'utf8mb4'; -- Filter by encoding
```

| Collation | Charset | Id | Default | Compiled | Sortlen | Pad_attribute |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci | utf8mb4 | 255 | Yes | Yes | 0 | NO PAD |
| utf8mb4_0900_as_ci | utf8mb4 | 305 |  | Yes | 0 | NO PAD |
| utf8mb4_0900_as_cs | utf8mb4 | 278 |  | Yes | 0 | NO PAD |
| utf8mb4_0900_bin | utf8mb4 | 309 |  | Yes | 1 | NO PAD |
| utf8mb4_bin | utf8mb4 | 46 |  | Yes | 1 | PAD SPACE |
| utf8mb4_croatian_ci | utf8mb4 | 245 |  | Yes | 8 | PAD SPACE |
| utf8mb4_cs_0900_ai_ci | utf8mb4 | 266 |  | Yes | 0 | NO PAD |
| utf8mb4_cs_0900_as_cs | utf8mb4 | 289 |  | Yes | 0 | NO PAD |
| utf8mb4_czech_ci | utf8mb4 | 234 |  | Yes | 8 | PAD SPACE |
| utf8mb4_danish_ci | utf8mb4 | 235 |  | Yes | 8 | PAD SPACE |

[...]

Collation names in MySQL use some common substrings to indicate certain features:

- `ci` / `cs` for Case Insensitive / Case Sensitive
- `ai` / `as` for Accent Sensitive / Accent Insensitive

... and some others ([full list here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/charset-collation-names.html)).

In MySQL, you can set collation at several levels:

- Server
- Database
- Table
- Column
- Connection
- Individual strings in SQL

So you always get one, either explicit or implicit.

Answer (score 0):

This type of question is simple to test.
Here I test is dbFiddle : you can run the same script, with other values if required in your database to check with your local settings, collation etc.

> ```
> create table sortable(
> val varchar(10));
> insert into sortable values
> ('A'),('B'),('a'),('b');
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
>
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> SELECT val
> FROM sortable
> ORDER BY val;
> ```
>
> ```
> | val |
> | :-- |
> | A   |
> | a   |
> | B   |
> | b   |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=f450805535d9d48e99df7fa0b64eb8ea)*

Answer (score 0):

If you want to switch to ASCII Code sorting you can change the order to sort by bynary value of the characters with the following:

`SELECT id, random_varchar`
`FROM table`
`ORDER BY NLSSORT(random_varchar, 'NLS_SORT = BINARY')`